# What is the translation express (adjective meaning fast) in Chinese?

Tags: translation, culture

I want to know the translation of the word "express" (both characters and pinyin) as you would describe an express courier service? 
Also, is there a new-invented word (maybe by the youth) that is used today to convey the meaning of express?

Answer (score 2):

'Express courier service' in Chinese is

[速遞](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/17879/)服務  or [快遞](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/34435/)服務

速遞/快遞 is shortened from '快速遞送/ 快速傳遞' (express delivery) . It can functions as an adjectival noun as in   **速遞**服務(**express delivery** service); **速遞**文件(**express delivery** document)

Comment: OK, Let's say I want to write American express. Can I say sudi American or American sudi?

Comment: https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E7%BE%8E%E5%9C%8B%E9%81%8B%E9%80%9A

Answer (score 1):

Express for train: *特快列车(Te Kuai Lie Che)*

Express for delivery service: *快递(Kuai Di)*

Comment: Is 快递(Kuai Di) used by the you generation? what I mean is the word modern and is ok to be said by someone young or what? Also is there kind of a short hand form for the word?

Comment: Yes. It's a relative new word, we used to call it "包裹"（packaging）back to China Post time. The China Post was the only company provide delivery service in China at that time. "快递" has only two characters, it's already short enough, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

[快递](http://baike.baidu.com/link?url=9-IvMtoqbQsESxkyr2KND21GtoEjKUf1Ejsf_CQwroBT1n8Ks2cQaSB0OYMmkwCVbstqfF3MGz5dhtS3duDvdl3PzY4gl9eiyvfzsh_ZnsC) （kuaidi)

In fact, all generations in China call express `快递`. We call it '快递' in many  cases.